# Possible to reset sessions for all users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, session-cookies

Due to change in authentication procedure I need to reset all sessions for all users, how do I do this in Rails 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the secret_key your app uses to encrypt cookies in config/initializers/secret_token.rb or you can change the name of the cookie key in config/initializers/session_store.rb either of these changes will invalidate all sessions and require them to be recreated (login again)