# Rails Delete_All but Still Looking for id=5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I recently switched my app from a gem to a by-hand shopping cart.  I created a new `orders` table, yet when I try to get into my app I get an error saying:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /
Couldn't find Order with 'id'=5
```

The error is called on this bit of my `application_controller`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_order

  def current_order
    if !session[:order_id].nil?
      Order.find(session[:order_id])  <<<<< THIS LINE
    else
      Order.new
    end
  end
end
```

I tried `order.delete_all` in my controller, but it is still looking for `id=5` for some reason.  I would try `db:drop db:create` but I have data on the production app I don't want to lose.

Is there any way to either:

1. Fix this error without messing up the database?
2. Drop/recreate just the orders table without destroying the rest of the database?

Also, I could be reading the problem wrong, so let me know if you think the solution lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with database at all. Well, almost. Certainly, nothing that will require dropping/recreating db structures.

Your `session[:order_id]` has a value that is not in the db. That's what you have to fix, the session. Or your handling of not-found records. For example, this will not raise an error.

```
 Order.where(id: session[:order_id]).first
```

Comment: What you're saying makes sense, but I'm not sure how to implement it.  I don't get this error in incognito mode, so I assume it's just an issue with the current session...

Comment: @Liz: yep, it is a problem with current session. Drop the cookies and _you_ should be good. To reset the session for all users, you can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21467250/125816).